# question mark with file extension after changing the name of multiple files using terminal

Tags: excel, macos, terminal

I renamed 500 files using excel and terminal command.
the problem is now the file have a '?' after the extension
for example abcd.wav? \I want to remove this question mark from all the files
trying find and replace didn't work.
This is the command I  used

perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/;' myfile.csv
while IFS=; read old new; do mv "$old" "$new"; done < myfile.csv

in myfile.cvs I have one column that contains the oldname.wav;newname.wav

Comment: That sounds like the result of having carriage returns at the end of lines in the .csv file (the DOS/Windows format), but the `perl` command *should've* removed those. View the file with `LC_ALL=C cat -vt myfile.csv`, and see if that shows "^M" (carriage return) or something else weird at the end of the lines. If its results are unclear, `xxd myfile.csv` will give and even more detailed dump of its contents.

Comment: yes, there is ^M in file name. what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the extraneous carriage returns from the ends of the filenames with this:

```
for file in *$'\r'; do mv -i "$file" "${file%$'\r'}"; done
```

I'm still a bit confused, though. That `perl` command *should* have removed the carriage returns from the .csv file; I'm not sure what went wrong there.